# Search text field does not returning any values

Tags: java, mysql, netbeans-8

In my employee payroll management project the search text field does not working..i use mysql workbench and java..
it does not returning any value..
How can i solve this error?
How my search text field is working????

My coding is here:

```
enter code here

        private void txt_searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
   try{ 
       String sql ="select * from Staff_information where id=? ";
   pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
   pst.setString(1,txt_search.getText());
   rs=pst.executeQuery();
   String add1 =rs.getString("id"); 
   txt_id.setText(add1);
   String add2 =rs.getString("first_name");
   txt_firstname.setText(add2); 
   String add3 =rs.getString("surname"); 
   txt_surname.setText(add3); 
   String add4 =rs.getString("Dob"); 
   txt_dob.setText(add4);
   String add5 =rs.getString("Email");
   txt_email.setText(add5); 
   String add6 =rs.getString("Telephone"); 
   txt_tel.setText(add6); 
   String add7 =rs.getString("Address");
   txt_address.setText(add7);
   String add8 =rs.getString("Department");
   txt_dep.setText(add8); 
   String add10 =rs.getString("Salary"); 
   txt_salary.setText(add10); 
   String add11 =rs.getString("Address2");
   txt_add2.setText(add11); 
   String add12 =rs.getString("Apartment"); 
   txt_apt.setText(add12); 
   String add13 =rs.getString("Post_code"); 
   txt_pc.setText(add13); 
   String add14 =rs.getString("Status");
   txt_status.setText(add14);
   String add15 =rs.getString("Date_hired");
   txt_doj.setText(add15); 
   String add16 =rs.getString("job_title");
   txt_job.setText(add16); 
   String add17 =rs.getString("Designation");
   txt_design.setText(add17); 
   byte[] image = rs.getBytes("Image"); 
   ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(image).getImage().getScaledInstance(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
   img.setIcon(imageIcon);
   }catch(Exception e){ 
   } finally { 
       try{
       rs.close();
       pst.close();
       } catch(Exception e){ 
       } }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The resultset's cursor is initially pointing to before the first row. you have to move the cursor to the row that contains the data within the resultset object in order to access the data. For that you can use either rs.first() or rs.next(). If you calls rs.first() it Moves the cursor to the first row in this ResultSet object on the other hand if you used rs.next() it Moves the cursor froward one row from its current position. if your SQL query returns only one record you can use rs.first(). call it between below lines

```
rs=pst.executeQuery();
//either rs.first() or rs.next()
String add1 =rs.getString("id");
```

Answer (score 1):

When you use JDBC to execute a query and fetch a result set, you get a set of records bundled into a `ResultSet` object. The `ResultSet` object is not one record, but a collection of zero or more records that match your SQL query results. When you execute the `rs=pst.executeQuery()` method, you get a `ResultSet` object in the `rs` variable. Like I mentioned, this Result Set will contain Zero, One or even more results based on the data in your database.

To retrieve the first record, you need to first call the `rs.next()` method so that the result set is pointing to the first record in your query results. To get the next record, you need to call the `rs.next()` again and again until you have finished parsing all the records in your result set. Without doing this, you cannot retrieve your query results from your result set object.

In your code, where you have these lines,

```
rs=pst.executeQuery();
String add1 =rs.getString("id");
```

Insert `rs.next()` after `rs=pst.executeQuery();`.

So your code becomes this:

```
private void txt_searchKeyReleased(java.awt.event.KeyEvent evt) {                                       
    try{
        String sql ="select * from Staff_information where id=? ";
        pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
        pst.setString(1,txt_search.getText());
        rs=pst.executeQuery();
        if(rs.next()){ // You need this line
            String add1 =rs.getString("id"); 
            txt_id.setText(add1);
            String add2 =rs.getString("first_name");
            txt_firstname.setText(add2); 
            String add3 =rs.getString("surname"); 
            txt_surname.setText(add3); 
            String add4 =rs.getString("Dob"); 
            txt_dob.setText(add4);
            String add5 =rs.getString("Email");
            txt_email.setText(add5); 
            String add6 =rs.getString("Telephone"); 
            txt_tel.setText(add6); 
            String add7 =rs.getString("Address");
            txt_address.setText(add7);
            String add8 =rs.getString("Department");
            txt_dep.setText(add8); 
            String add10 =rs.getString("Salary"); 
            txt_salary.setText(add10); 
            String add11 =rs.getString("Address2");
            txt_add2.setText(add11); 
            String add12 =rs.getString("Apartment"); 
            txt_apt.setText(add12); 
            String add13 =rs.getString("Post_code"); 
            txt_pc.setText(add13); 
            String add14 =rs.getString("Status");
            txt_status.setText(add14);
            String add15 =rs.getString("Date_hired");
            txt_doj.setText(add15); 
            String add16 =rs.getString("job_title");
            txt_job.setText(add16); 
            String add17 =rs.getString("Designation");
            txt_design.setText(add17); 
            byte[] image = rs.getBytes("Image"); 
            ImageIcon imageIcon = new ImageIcon(new ImageIcon(image).getImage().getScaledInstance(img.getWidth(), img.getHeight(), Image.SCALE_SMOOTH));
            img.setIcon(imageIcon);
        }
        else {
            // Handle cases where data is not found.
        }
    }catch(Exception e){ 
    } finally { 
        try{
            rs.close();
            pst.close();
        } catch(Exception e){ 
        }
    }
}
```

**Pro tip**: *It is **not** a good practice to have SQL statements written inside your Swing Event Listeners. Try moving this piece of code to a different class. You will also need to handle cases where there may be more than one record in your result set.*

Also see [this tutorial](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/retrieving.html) from Oracle for more details:

Hope this helps!

Comment: I've update my answer - see the first two paragraphs. Hope it helps.

Comment: See the 7th line in my code snippet that contains `rs.next()`.